# Unable to index matrix in C++?

Tags: c++

Newbie to C++, I'm providing matrix index as user input. Unable to run this script.
Suggestions!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string fools[3][4] = {{"cat","dog","mon","junk"},
                          {"dad","mom","sis","fath"},
                          {"fox","cow","buff","chip"}};
```

```
for(int i=0; i < 3;i++)
        {
        for(int j=0; j< 4;j++)
        {
        cout << fools[i][j]<< " " << flush;
        }
        cout << endl;
        }
```

```
    cout << "Enter the matrix index:" <<flush;
    int num1,num2;
    cin >> fools[num1][num2];
    if(num1 == 0 && num2 == 2){
        cout << "Your name monday" << endl;
    }
     else if (num1 == 1 && num2 == 3){
        cout <<"no faith" << endl;
    }else if (num1 == 2 && num2 == 1){
        cout <<"your name cow" << endl;
    }else{
    cout <<"not valid"<<endl;
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not a script, it's a C++ program that should be compiled with C++ compliler. What errors do you observe?

Comment: `Unable to run this script.` Please be more specific.

Comment: I figured out were it went wrong. Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing this:

```
cin >> fools[num1][num2];
```

The input read from the console is directly the value in the fools matrix.
If you do this:

```
cin >> fools[0][0];
```

whatever you enter in the console will modify "cat" and store the new value as a string. Suppose if you enter 0 1, it will change "cat" to "0 1".
You need to take the row and column index as input like this:

```
cin >> num1 >> num2;
```

In your code `num1` and `num2` are uninitialised and contain some random garbage value as is the case with all uninitialised local variables in C++.
Let's assume `num1` and `num2` contain random values 12 and 34.
`fools[12][34]` will cause undefined behaviour because your matrix doesn't have a 34th column or a 12th row.

Answer (score 3):

The error is in this line

`cin >> fools[num1][num2];`

This line attempts to read a string value from stdin and put into array.

But you are expecting two integers, or indices (Hopefully space separated)
This is the way to go.

`cin >> num1 >> num2;`

In your code you have garbage value in `num1` and `num2`

Comment: Who says not valid? I am not ready to expect that the program says 0 2 not valid. xD. You have to be more specific. Does the program crashes or something else happens?

Comment: I mess up with other program, works fine. Sorry for hassle.Thanks!